# type level pattern matching in scala

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching, shapeless, type-level-computation

Ideally I'd like to write Haskell style pattern matching on the type level in Scala, something like this:

Can shapeless be used for something like this ?

```
object Test{


  type F[Int] = String
  type F[Boolean] = Int  // but this line does not compile

  implicitly[String =:= F[Int]]
  implicitly[Int =:= F[Boolean]]

}
```

In this example if `F` takes `Int` then it returns `String` and if it takes `Boolean` then it returns `Int`.

**Clarification (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50896532/2707792))**

Here is how I'd like to use these types in functions and typeclasses:

```
  abstract class WrappedF[T] {
    type F
    type Unwrap = T
  }

  type F[X <: WrappedF[_]] = X#F

  class IntF      extends WrappedF[Int]     { type F = StringF }
  class BooleanF  extends WrappedF[Boolean] { type F = IntF }
  class StringF   extends WrappedF[String]  { type F = Nothing }

  implicitly[String =:= F[IntF]#Unwrap]
  implicitly[Int =:=    F[BooleanF]#Unwrap]
  implicitly[String =:= F[F[BooleanF]]#Unwrap]

  // this is a type class definition where `V` is a member of the `Test` class
  // `f`'s type should be defined by `V`, but it does not work :(


  trait Test[V <: WrappedF[V]]{
    def f(a: F[V]#Unwrap): F[V]#Unwrap // this does not compile
  }

  implicit object TestImpl extends Test[IntF]{
    override def f(a: F[IntF]#Unwrap): F[IntF]#Unwrap = {
      val z: F[IntF]#Unwrap = "fd"+a
      z
    }
  }
```

Comment: I found something like this https://gist.github.com/cvogt/c9e602231646385f35c5471e54e7c67b

but I don't really see how that can answer this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here two non-shapeless solutions.

1. A little type-level table of constants with funny names:

   ```
   type F = {
     type Int = java.lang.String
     type Boolean = scala.Int
   }

   implicitly[String =:= F#Int]
   implicitly[Int =:= F#Boolean]
   ```

   Here, `F` is a type with two type members that have names `Int` and `Boolean` (could be `I` and `B`, those two constants aren't really connected with `Int` or `Boolean` in any way). This doesn't compose: you can't write down something like `F#F#Int`.
2. You can lift every type `T` for which you want to define `F` into a type that has both `T` and `F[T]` as type members:

   ```
   abstract class WrappedF[T] {
     type F
     type Unwrap = T
   }
   type F[X <: WrappedF[_]] = X#F
   class IntF extends WrappedF[Int] { type F = StringF }
   class BooleanF extends WrappedF[Boolean] { type F = IntF }
   class StringF extends WrappedF[String] { type F = Nothing }

   implicitly[String =:= F[IntF]#Unwrap]
   implicitly[Int =:= F[BooleanF]#Unwrap]
   implicitly[String =:= F[F[BooleanF]]#Unwrap]
   ```

   This adds more noise because of `...F` and `#Unwrap`, but is purely a type-level computation, and it composes (as the last example shows).

---

**Update (better suited for abstracting over `V <: WrappedF`)**

In your code under "Clarification", you were missing `F <: WrappedF` bound on the type member `F`:

```
  abstract class WrappedF {
    type F <: WrappedF
    type Unwrap
  }

  type F[X <: WrappedF] = X#F

  class IntF      extends WrappedF { type Unwrap = Int;     type F = StringF }
  class BooleanF  extends WrappedF { type Unwrap = Boolean; type F = IntF }
  class StringF   extends WrappedF { type Unwrap = String;  type F = Nothing }

  implicitly[String =:= F[IntF]#Unwrap]
  implicitly[Int    =:= F[BooleanF]#Unwrap]
  implicitly[String =:= F[F[BooleanF]]#Unwrap]

  trait Test[V <: WrappedF]{
    def f(a: F[V]#Unwrap): F[V]#Unwrap // this does not compile
  }

  implicit object TestImpl extends Test[IntF] {
    override def f(a: String): String = {
      val z: F[IntF]#Unwrap = "fd" + a
      z
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow, this looks really nice !

Comment: @jhegedus It's constrained in the sense that it would work only in "top-down" manner: when you start with the more abstract `TypeF`s, perform some type-level computations, and finally unwrap everything into the actual underlying types. It doesn't give you a way to go from `Int` to `IntF`. For this, it seems that you would need something like HTNW's approach with implicit values.

Comment: thanks Andrey, I added a comment to my question, how I would like to use these types, in functions, in typeclass-es ...

Comment: @jhegedus Updated answer, now works with `V <: WrappedF` too.

Comment: Thanks, I check that out.

Comment: Thanks again Andrey, it seems to work nice : https://scalafiddle.io/sf/kDlKJF9/1 , let me play around with it for a bit so that I understand how I can use this to create a type safe REST-API with SCALAJS+SCALA :) - but it seems promising ..I'm still looking for some nice type safe architecture for the communication, that is.

Comment: I'll plan to publish the resulting mini-full-stack-end-to-end-scala-singlepageapp-web-framework to be open source, once it is ready :) who knows when :)

Answer (score 5):

You use a typeclass style implicit structure with a type member.

```
// sealed for closed family
class F[I] { type O }
object F {
  type Rel[I, O0] = F[I] { type O = O0 }
  /* private */ def mkF[I, O0]: Rel[I, O0] = new F[I] { override type O = O0 }
  implicit val fInt: Rel[Int, String] = mkF
  implicit val fBoolean: Rel[Boolean, Int] = mkF
  def apply[I](implicit f: F[I]): f.type = f // f.type survives the refinement (see what breaks on removal)
}

locally { val temp = F[Int]; implicitly[temp.O =:= String] }
locally { val temp = F[Boolean]; implicitly[temp.O =:= Int] }
locally { val temp0 = F[Boolean]; val temp1 = F[temp0.O]; implicitly[temp1.O =:= String] }
```

Comment: looks interesting, let me give it a spin